# Vehicle drop down selector

Tags: jquery, html, dropdown

Chasing some help on this one, unfortunately Javascript is not my forte; I am creating a simple drop down vehicle make, model and year selector which leads through to a link which is created dynamically depending on the users options selected.

Effectively the user should be able to select a make and then have a model show up which is associated with that make and finally a year that is associated with the model selected. I have been able to get the make and model selection to work but when I attempt the same thing by adding in the year it starts showing the year in place of the model.

Can someone please assist with this? My code is below along with a link to the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Yash91/qtd7patd/

```js
function showURL() {
    var d1 = $("#make").find(":selected").attr("class");
    var d2 = $("#model").find(":selected").attr("class");
    var d3 = $("#year").find(":selected").attr("class");
    var url = ("http://www.web.com.au/" + d1 + "/" + d2 + "/" + d3);
    window.location = url;
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var $make = $( '#make' ),
  $model = $( '#model' ),
    $options = $model.find( 'option' );
    
$make.on( 'change', function() {
 $model.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

var $model = $( '#model' ),
  $year = $( '#year' ),
    $options = $year.find( 'option' );
    
$model.on( 'change', function() {
 $year.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Vehicle Brand Selector List -->
<select name="make" id="make">
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="0">Make</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="1">BMW</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="2">Daewoo</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="3">Ford</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="4">Holden</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="5">Honda</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="6">Hyundai</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="7">Isuzu</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="8">Kia</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="9">Lexus</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="10">Mazda</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="11">Mitsubishi</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="12">Nissan</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="13">Peugeot</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="14">Subaru</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="15">Suzuki</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="16">Toyota</option>
 <option class="vehicle-search" value="17">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Model List -->
<select name="model" id="model">
 <option value="0">Model</option>
 <option class="318i" value="1">318i</option>
 <option class="lanos" value="2">Lanos</option>
 <option class="courier" value="3">Courier</option>
 <option class="falcon" value="3">Falcon</option>
 <option class="festiva" value="3">Festiva</option>
 <option class="fiesta" value="3">Fiesta</option>
 <option class="focus" value="3">Focus</option>
 <option class="laser" value="3">Laser</option>
 <option class="ranger" value="3">Ranger</option>
 <option class="territory" value="3">Territory</option>
 <option class="astra" value="4">Astra</option>
 <option class="barina" value="4">Barina</option>
 <option class="captiva" value="4">Captiva</option>
 <option class="colorado" value="4">Colorado</option>
 <option class="commodore" value="4">Commodore</option>
 <option class="cruze" value="4">Cruze</option>
 <option class="rodeo" value="4">Rodeo</option>
 <option class="viva" value="4">Viva</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Year List -->
<select name="year" id="year">
 <option value="0">Year</option>
 <option class="1998-2005" value="1">1998-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="2">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" onclick="showURL();" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the same `$options` for year too.

Change your code like below.

```js
function showURL() {
    var d1 = $("#identifier").find(":selected").attr("class");
    var url = ("/store/vehicle-selected/" + d1);
    window.location = url;
    return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var $make = $( '#make' ),
  $model = $( '#model' ),
    $options = $model.find( 'option' );
    
$make.on( 'change', function() {
 $model.html( $options.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]') );
  $model.trigger( 'change' );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

var $model = $( '#model' ),
  $year = $( '#year' ),
    $yearOptions = $year.find( 'option' );
    
$model.on( 'change', function() {
 $year.html( $yearOptions.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' ) );
  $year.trigger( 'change' );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

var $year = $( '#year' ),
  $identifier = $( '#identifier' ),
    $identifierOptions = $identifier.find( 'option' );
    
$year.on( 'change', function() {
  var filteredIdetifiers = $identifierOptions.filter( '[value="' + this.value + '"]' );
    debugger
  if(!($("#make").val() == 3 && $("#model option:selected").text()  == 'Falcon')) {
       filteredIdetifiers = filteredIdetifiers.filter(function(i,e){ return e.value !== '3'    });
    }
    $identifier.html(filteredIdetifiers);
  $identifier.trigger( 'change' );
} ).trigger( 'change' );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Vehicle Brand Selector List -->
<select name="make" id="make">
 <option value="0">Make</option>
 <option value="1">BMW</option>
 <option value="2">Daewoo</option>
 <option value="3">Ford</option>
 <option value="4">Holden</option>
 <option value="5">Honda</option>
 <option value="6">Hyundai</option>
 <option value="7">Isuzu</option>
 <option value="8">Kia</option>
 <option value="9">Lexus</option>
 <option value="10">Mazda</option>
 <option value="11">Mitsubishi</option>
 <option value="12">Nissan</option>
 <option value="13">Peugeot</option>
 <option value="14">Subaru</option>
 <option value="15">Suzuki</option>
 <option value="16">Toyota</option>
 <option value="17">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Model List -->
<select name="model" id="model">
 <option value="0">Model</option>
 <option class="318i" value="1">318i</option>
 <option class="lanos" value="2">Lanos</option>
 <option class="courier" value="3">Courier</option>
 <option class="falcon" value="3">Falcon</option>
 <option class="festiva" value="3">Festiva</option>
 <option class="fiesta" value="3">Fiesta</option>
 <option class="focus" value="3">Focus</option>
 <option class="laser" value="3">Laser</option>
 <option class="ranger" value="3">Ranger</option>
 <option class="territory" value="3">Territory</option>
 <option class="astra" value="4">Astra</option>
 <option class="barina" value="4">Barina</option>
 <option class="captiva" value="4">Captiva</option>
 <option class="colorado" value="4">Colorado</option>
 <option class="commodore" value="4">Commodore</option>
 <option class="cruze" value="4">Cruze</option>
 <option class="rodeo" value="4">Rodeo</option>
 <option class="viva" value="4">Viva</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Year List -->
<select name="year" id="year">
 <option value="0">Year</option>
 <option value="1">1998</option>
 <option value="1">1999</option>
 <option value="1">2000</option>
 <option value="1">2001</option>
 <option value="1">2002</option>
 <option value="1">2003</option>
 <option value="1">2004</option>
 <option value="1">2005</option>
 <option value="2">1997</option>
 <option value="2">1998</option>
 <option value="2">1999</option>
 <option value="2">2000</option>
 <option value="2">2001</option>
 <option value="2">2002</option>
 <option value="2">2003</option>
 <option value="3">1991-1999</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2007</option>
 <option value="5">1997-2007</option>
 <option value="3">2002</option>
 <option value="3">2003</option>
 <option value="3">2004</option>
 <option value="3">2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Identity List -->
<select name="identifier" id="identifier">
 <option value="0">Type</option>
 <option class="E46" value="1">E46</option>
 <option class="1997-2003" value="2">N/A</option>
 <option class="1997-2007" value="4">N/A</option>
 <option class="1997-2007" value="5">N/A</option>
 <option class="5041618" value="3">BA</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">AU</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="3">AU2</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">N/A</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
 <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" onclick="showURL();" />
```

Comment: Thank-you very much for your response! That seems to have fixed the issue with the year for most of the vehicles, however for an option like BMW as it only has a single model the year doesn't seem to kick in as it seems the code doesn't detect the change. It also looks like it doesn't clear the years when the model changes, is there anyway to make these two things function correctly? Again appreciate the reply! :)

Comment: @Yash check the updated answer, you need to trigger the change event. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank-you soo much! Makes absolute sense now. Again appreciate you taking the time to answer :)

Comment: I have updated my fiddle to the below; 
https://jsfiddle.net/Yash91/gjwvb4cz/

Seems to be working now, but am facing a new issue, I have added a fourth drop down box which is designed to allow the user to breakdown the drop downs further. However the fourth box is only meant to show up when the user selects a particular vehicle, for example a Ford Falcon should show BA, AU & AU2. But these options show up for all Ford vehicles, is there anyway I can lock this fourth box down to certain choices only?

Comment: check updated answer! you need to handle conditions as per requirement.