# Car Make/Model dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm setting up a new form on my site, and I'm using some code I found here ([Vehicle drop down selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450566/vehicle-drop-down-selector)). However, I'm using this code within a form, and once the form is submitted, the values for make/model aren't changed to their respective names, instead showing their form values. Being a complete JS noob, how would I go about changing the values submitted from values to make/model names?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $make = $('#make'),
    $model = $('#model'),
    $options = $model.find('option');

  $make.on('change', function() {
    $model.html($options.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
    $model.trigger('change');
  }).trigger('change');

  var $model = $('#model'),
    $year = $('#year'),
    $yearOptions = $year.find('option');

  $model.on('change', function() {
    $year.html($yearOptions.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]'));
    $year.trigger('change');
  }).trigger('change');

  var $year = $('#year'),
    $identifier = $('#identifier'),
    $identifierOptions = $identifier.find('option');

  $year.on('change', function() {
    var filteredIdetifiers = $identifierOptions.filter('[value="' + this.value + '"]');
    debugger
    if (!($("#make").val() == 3 && $("#model option:selected").text() == 'Falcon')) {
      filteredIdetifiers = filteredIdetifiers.filter(function(i, e) {
        return e.value !== '3'
      });
    }
    $identifier.html(filteredIdetifiers);
    $identifier.trigger('change');
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Vehicle Brand Selector List -->
<select name="make" id="make">
  <option value="0">Make</option>
  <option value="1">BMW</option>
  <option value="2">Daewoo</option>
  <option value="3">Ford</option>
  <option value="4">Holden</option>
  <option value="5">Honda</option>
  <option value="6">Hyundai</option>
  <option value="7">Isuzu</option>
  <option value="8">Kia</option>
  <option value="9">Lexus</option>
  <option value="10">Mazda</option>
  <option value="11">Mitsubishi</option>
  <option value="12">Nissan</option>
  <option value="13">Peugeot</option>
  <option value="14">Subaru</option>
  <option value="15">Suzuki</option>
  <option value="16">Toyota</option>
  <option value="17">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Model List -->
<select name="model" id="model">
  <option value="0">Model</option>
  <option class="318i" value="1">318i</option>
  <option class="lanos" value="2">Lanos</option>
  <option class="courier" value="3">Courier</option>
  <option class="falcon" value="3">Falcon</option>
  <option class="festiva" value="3">Festiva</option>
  <option class="fiesta" value="3">Fiesta</option>
  <option class="focus" value="3">Focus</option>
  <option class="laser" value="3">Laser</option>
  <option class="ranger" value="3">Ranger</option>
  <option class="territory" value="3">Territory</option>
  <option class="astra" value="4">Astra</option>
  <option class="barina" value="4">Barina</option>
  <option class="captiva" value="4">Captiva</option>
  <option class="colorado" value="4">Colorado</option>
  <option class="commodore" value="4">Commodore</option>
  <option class="cruze" value="4">Cruze</option>
  <option class="rodeo" value="4">Rodeo</option>
  <option class="viva" value="4">Viva</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Year List -->
<select name="year" id="year">
  <option value="0">Year</option>
  <option value="1">1998</option>
  <option value="1">1999</option>
  <option value="1">2000</option>
  <option value="1">2001</option>
  <option value="1">2002</option>
  <option value="1">2003</option>
  <option value="1">2004</option>
  <option value="1">2005</option>
  <option value="2">1997</option>
  <option value="2">1998</option>
  <option value="2">1999</option>
  <option value="2">2000</option>
  <option value="2">2001</option>
  <option value="2">2002</option>
  <option value="2">2003</option>
  <option value="3">1991-1999</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2007</option>
  <option value="5">1997-2007</option>
  <option value="3">2002</option>
  <option value="3">2003</option>
  <option value="3">2004</option>
  <option value="3">2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option value="4">1997-2005</option>
</select>
<!-- Vehicle Identity List -->
<select name="identifier" id="identifier">
  <option value="0">Type</option>
  <option class="E46" value="1">E46</option>
  <option class="1997-2003" value="2">N/A</option>
  <option class="1997-2007" value="4">N/A</option>
  <option class="1997-2007" value="5">N/A</option>
  <option class="5041618" value="3">BA</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="3">AU</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="3">AU2</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">N/A</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
  <option class="1997-2005" value="4">1997-2005</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In every `<option>` tag there is an attribute called value. This value attribute is what is returned at as the value of the dropdown when that option is selected. Seems like in the code you found they are all simply set to numbers. You can set them to be whatever you want though:

```html
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>

<option class="focus" value="Focus">Focus</option>
```

**FIXING DYNAMIC OPTIONS**

I see that modifying the values directly affect how the dynamic options are displayed. For example the value attribute of the car model dropdown is used to filter the car make dropdown by only displaying options with the same value. Instead of using the model dropdown's value attributes to compare with make, we can add a new data- attribute called `data-make` and filter the model dropdown based on that instead. This allows you to freely modify the value attribute in model. The example code below shows this. You would need to modify your JS so model affects year, and year affects identifier in the same way.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $make = $('#make'),
    $model = $('#model'),
    $options = $model.find('option');

  $make.on('change', function() {
    // We now filter model using the data-make attribute, not value
    $model.html($options.filter('[data-make="' + this.value + '"]'));
    $model.trigger('change');
  }).trigger('change');
  
  $('#carForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let formData = $(this).serializeArray();
      let data = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < formData.length; i++) {
        data[formData[i].name] = formData[i].value;
      }
      
      alert('Make: ' + data.make + '\nModel: ' + data.model);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="carForm">
  <select name="make" id="make">
    <option value="0">Make</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option> <!-- These values are now make names -->
    <option value="Daewoo">Daewoo</option>
    <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
  </select>
  <!-- Vehicle Model List -->
  <!-- Notice the new "data-make" attributes for each -->
  <select name="model" id="model">
    <option value="0">Model</option>
    <option class="318i" value="318i" data-make="BMW">318i</option>
    <option class="lanos" value="Lanos" data-make="Daewoo">Lanos</option>
    <option class="courier" value="Courier" data-make="Ford">Courier</option>
    <option class="falcon" value="Falcon" data-make="Ford">Falcon</option>
    <option class="festiva" value="Festiva" data-make="Ford">Festiva</option>
    <option class="fiesta" value="Fiesta" data-make="Ford">Fiesta</option>
    <option class="focus" value="Focus" data-make="Ford">Focus</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI The use of the `value` attribute in an `option` element is optional. If not specified, the `value` of the `option` becomes the text of the `option` element.

Comment: @ScottMarcus is correct, however since the original code is using the `value` attribute to filter, it will still require modification!

Comment: Thanks Fellas! I appreciate the answers, will implement this. Also, I was wondering since I'm not making use of year here if there was an easy way to remove it? @kht

Comment: @JoshJacobs If you're not using year or identifier then you can simply take the code above, just add/remove options inside the select dropdowns as needed

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected option text like this.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var make = $make.find(':selected').text();
}
```

But it would be good practice to set the value you expect to return as the option value and use a data attribute or class to handle the filtering logic.